# Im getting an error regarding TemplateView in CBV django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

Class-based TemplateView are not working, help me find the error

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.base import View,TemplateView
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
class home(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['injectme'] = 'injected'
        return context
```

url.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from basicapp import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$',views.home.as_view(),name = 'home'),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

> TypeError at /
>   expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple
>   Request Method:   GET
>   Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/ Django Version:  2.2 Exception
>   Type: TypeError Exception Value:   expected str, bytes or os.PathLike
>   object, not tuple Exception
>   Location: /anaconda3/envs/mydjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/posixpath.py in
>   join, line 80 Python
>   Executable:   /anaconda3/envs/mydjangoEnv/bin/python Python
>   Version:  3.7.3 Python Path:
>   ['/Users/faiq/Desktop/exercise/CBV/advance',
>   '/anaconda3/envs/mydjangoEnv/lib/python37.zip',
>   '/anaconda3/envs/mydjangoEnv/lib/python3.7',
>   '/anaconda3/envs/mydjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', 
>   '/anaconda3/envs/mydjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages'] Server
>   time: Wed, 8 May 2019 23:02:58 +0000

Comment: Can you provide your `urls.py`?

Comment: provided, now can you figure out?

Comment: No, that's honestly works just fine on my end. Does it works without `get_context_data`?